# How to restrict duplicacy when getting data from database in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

I am fetching data from database using hibernate. I have 3 tables in my db and i have created 3 entity classes for them. I am fetching results on the basis of two criterias profession of user and city of user.

Here is my **DAO** class

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
public List<User> getUsersWithSameProfessionsById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Profession p1, Profession p2, Address a JOIN p2.user u WHERE p1.u_id=:id AND p2.profession=p1.profession AND a.uid=u.id";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setLong("id", id);
    query.setMaxResults(10);

    Set<User> foo = new HashSet<User>(query.list());

    Set<User> foo1 = new HashSet<User>();

    Query query1=null;
    if(professionList.size()<10){

        String queryString1 = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Address c1, Address c2, Address a JOIN c2.user u WHERE c1.uid=:id AND c2.city=c1.city AND a.uid=u.id";
        query1 = session.createQuery(queryString1);
        query1.setLong("id", id);

        foo1.addAll(query1.list());

    }

    List<User> professionList3 = new ArrayList<User>();
    Set<User> foo2 = new HashSet<User>();
    foo2.addAll(foo);
    foo2.addAll(foo1);
    professionList3.addAll(foo2);

    return professionList3;
}
```

Here i am fetching records from first query on the basis of profession but if results are less than 10 then i am running second query on the basis of city.
But if results are matching with both criterias then i am getting duplicate results and i dont want it..i want if results have been come in first query then those results not come in second query. I am new in hql queries so please help me.

Thanx in advance

Comment: cann't you use NOT IN clause?

Comment: Thanx for your reply... but i am unable to join queries using NOT IN clause... can you do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to tweak queries, you could take the following approach

Override equals and hashcode in User Object so that you can treat two user objects as same if their id's as same.

The use a Set to hold your data. Duplicates will be discarded. Finally return the set or simply transform the set to a list

```
list.addAll(set)
```

Comment: but how will i get query result in set... now i am getting list of result like list= query.list();

Comment: Set<User> foo = new HashSet<User>(yourList);

Comment: thanx @jozzy its working but the results are not coming in sequence...i want results in sequence like the results from first query should be on top and if records are less than 10 then second query results should be in bottom.

Answer (score 1):

On top of jozzy's answer and comments you can use a TreeSet instead of a HashSet which is a SortedSet implementation and will keep your user records sorted.

So it should go like,

```
Set<User> foo = new TreeSet<User>(yourList);
```

Comment: but after adding both results i am getting more than 10 results while i want  only 10

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are selecting address "SELECT DISTINCT a ".. may be you meant "SELECT DISTINCT u". 
Assuming you are selecting users, after doing your first query you can collect the userIds in a list..

```
List<Long> alreadyFoundUserIds = new ArrayList<>();
for(User user : foo){
    alreadyFoundUserIds.add(user.getId()); 
}
```

Then in your second query you can exclude those users and fetch remaining
(10 - foo.size() ).

```
   String queryString1 = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM Address c1, Address c2, Address a JOIN c2.user u WHERE c1.uid=:id AND c2.city=c1.city AND a.uid=u.id
 AND u.id NOT IN (:alreadyFoundUserIds )   ";

        query1 = session.createQuery(queryString1);
        query1.setLong("id", id);
        query1.setParameterList("alreadyFoundUserIds ", alreadyFoundUserIds ); 
        query1.setMaxResults(10 - alreadyFoundUserIds.size());
```

Comment: okay thanx for your reply..but how can i return only 10 records..i am getting more than 10 results in list

Comment: No you cannot get more than 10, first query will return max 10, second query will return max 10-firstqueryResultSize..example if first query returns 3 , second query returns 10-3 = 7 , so total you will have 3 +7 = 10.

Comment: actually i am using Set now and when i am passing my both lists to set then duplicacy is removed from results then results are less than 10

Comment: i have one another problem... which id i am passing into url to gwt results i am getting that id record too in my results... how can i remove that?

Comment: i think you have to post another question for GWT , its not related to hibernate,sql like this question. i have no idea about gwt.